# How can I build a query to view the same value in 20 or more tables in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

Scenarios:

Table 1

```
Name       ID      dept 
John       112      Fin
Mary       113       Act
```

Table 2

```
Name       email     
John        John@gmail.com
Mary          Max@gmail.com
```

Table 3

```
Name        Supervisor 
John          Kelly 
Mary           Adam
```

Table 4

```
Namevalue      Salary 
John            1000
Mary             1000
```

**Expected Output:**

I would like to know the occurrence of John and Mary in all these tables. There are more than 20 tables in difference database.

Comment: it's going to be cumbersome, but use joins.

Comment: I also thought of using it, but having so many tables for the same records it is going to be cumbersome. If there is no other way I would use it. Thank You for the information

Comment: Why is your data so fragmented? can you refactor your database?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, specify the master table according to data quality, use this table as base and then use left joins to concat with other tables.

But, I think, there is a design problem in the database so maybe creating keys for each user can be useful.

For example, name + surname + User Something to make records unique then use joins otherwise all records will duplicate.

Comment: Thank you for the information Dogan. I would appreciate if you could provide any examples.